# JavaScript get window X/Y position for scroll

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping to find a way to get the current viewable window's position (relative to the total page width/height) so I can use it to force a scroll from one section to another. However, there seems to be a tremendous amount of options when it comes to guessing which object holds the true X/Y for your browser.

Which of these do I need to make sure IE 6+, FF 2+, and Chrome/Safari work?

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
window.pageXOffset
window.pageYOffset
document.documentElement.clientWidth
document.documentElement.clientHeight
document.documentElement.scrollLeft
document.documentElement.scrollTop
document.body.clientWidth
document.body.clientHeight
document.body.scrollLeft
document.body.scrollTop
```

And are there any others? Once I know where the window is I can set an event chain that will slowly call `window.scrollBy(x,y);` until it reaches my desired point.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

The method jQuery (v1.10) uses to find this is:

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
var left = (window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft) - (doc.clientLeft || 0);
var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);
```

That is:

- It tests for `window.pageXOffset` first and uses that if it exists.
- Otherwise, it uses `document.documentElement.scrollLeft`.
- It then subtracts `document.documentElement.clientLeft` if it exists.

The subtraction of `document.documentElement.clientLeft` / `Top` only appears to be required to correct for situations where you have applied a border (not padding or margin, but actual border) to the root element, and at that, possibly only in certain browsers.

---

**Update February 2024:**

Nowadays, jQuery basically just uses `window.pageXOffset` and `window.pageYOffset` without any of the rest.

```
var left = window.pageXOffset;
var top = window.pageYOffset;
```

Interestingly, `pageXOffset` and `pageYOffset` are **non-standard**.  The standards based equivalent is `scrollX` and `scrollY`.  But all modern browsers place an alias of those to `pageXOffset` and `pageYOffset` for compatibility, and their use in something as important as jQuery signifies they're pretty safe to use into the foreseeable future.

If you don't care about Internet Explorer 11 or earlier (which you probably don't need to at this point), then you can use `scrollX` and `scrollY`.

Comment: Thomas -- you're totally right.  My bad.  Comments removed.  I re-read your comment and realized that your solution wasn't a Jquery solution at all.   Apologies.  Modded up.

Comment: It works now. I think they had a very temporary bug in webkit and they fixed it already. I wrote a plugin the completely broke because of that bug and users reported to me of this. Very scary such basic things might break

Comment: Is this the code for $(window).scrollTop(); ? It would probably be useful to include the jQuery method as well in this answer.

Comment: The code I posted is a paraphrasing of what became `jQuery.fn.offset()`.
`scrollTop()` / `scrollLeft()` do basically the same, but don't subtract clientTop / clientLeft.

Comment: What is the method?

Comment: As I said above this is from jQuery's `jQuery.fn.offset()` function, though it is paraphrased rather than copied directly.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the jQuery equivalent math? Just for followers use. Thanks!

Comment: scrollY has no support in IE and potentially poor support in Edge and Safari

Answer (score 235):

Maybe more simple;

```
var top  = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
    left = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
```

Credits: [so.dom.js#L492](https://github.com/k-gun/so/blob/4.8.1/so.dom.js#L492)

Comment: Perfectly cross browser safe! Best solution.

Comment: That worked better than the answer code, but... the answer code doesn't worked, not a bit...

Comment: I wonder why not just use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` which works everywhere.

Comment: These days, all of the above are aliases of window.scrollY on all modern browsers, with the exception of MSIE (all versions).  As long as MSIE11 is still on the scene window.pageYOffset is probably the best works-anywhere until you can drop MSIE altogether.

Answer (score 39):

Using pure javascript you can use [Window.scrollX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollX) and [Window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollY)

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    var top = this.scrollY,
        left =this.scrollX;
}, false);
```

**Notes**

> The pageXOffset property is an alias for the scrollX property, and The
>   pageYOffset property is an alias for the scrollY property:

```
window.pageXOffset == window.scrollX; // always true
window.pageYOffset == window.scrollY; // always true
```

Here is a quick demo

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  
    var top = this.scrollY,
        left = this.scrollX;
  
    var horizontalScroll = document.querySelector(".horizontalScroll"),
        verticalScroll = document.querySelector(".verticalScroll");
    
    horizontalScroll.innerHTML = "Scroll X: " + left + "px";
      verticalScroll.innerHTML = "Scroll Y: " + top + "px";
  
}, false);
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
:root{height: 200vh;width: 200vw}
.wrapper{
    position: fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:0px;
    width:320px;
    background: black;
    color: green;
    height: 64px;
}
.wrapper div{
    display: inline;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 64px
}
.horizontalScroll{color: orange}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
    <div class=horizontalScroll>Scroll (x,y) to </div>
    <div class=verticalScroll>see me in action</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The page you linked to says "For cross-browser compatibility, use window.pageYOffset instead of window.scrollY."

Comment: This doesn't work for IE. IE requires something like `window.pageYOffset`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this has not been mentioned due to this article been 11 years old.

But currently I am using window.scrollY (inside an onscroll event listner and a throttle function) and it works just fine most of the time.
And when it doesn't I use intersectionObserver API for similar effect  which is also a fairly new feature I guess.

```
if (window.scrollY > desiredAmount) {
   doThis();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function FastScrollUp()
{
     window.scroll(0,0)
};

function FastScrollDown()
{
     $i = document.documentElement.scrollHeight ; 
     window.scroll(0,$i)
};
 var step = 20;
 var h,t;
 var y = 0;
function SmoothScrollUp()
{
     h = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
     y += step;
     window.scrollBy(0, -step)
     if(y >= h )
       {clearTimeout(t); y = 0; return;}
     t = setTimeout(function(){SmoothScrollUp()},20);

};


function SmoothScrollDown()
{
     h = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
     y += step;
     window.scrollBy(0, step)
     if(y >= h )
       {clearTimeout(t); y = 0; return;}
     t = setTimeout(function(){SmoothScrollDown()},20);

}
```