# $(window).scrollTop() vs. $(document).scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, document, scrolltop

What's the difference between:

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

and

```
$(document).scrollTop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: 'html' or 'body' for setter (depend on browser)... 'window' for getter... cf Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/uCrLa/

Answer (score 158, accepted):

They are both going to have **the same effect**.

However, as pointed out in the comments: **`$(window).scrollTop()` is supported by more web browsers** than `$('html').scrollTop()`.

Comment: it returns 0 in IE8 (although my page is in quirks mode, which may play a factor)

Comment: $('html').scrollTop() is not cross-browser (as a setter it doesn't work at least in Chrome). The most crossbrowser way to do it for now is: $(window).scrollTop() as a getter, $('html,body').scrollTop(offset) as a setter.

Comment: According to [this reference](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), without arguments `scrollTop` doesn't scroll anywhere, but just returns the current scroll location.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - If only that were actually true. `$(window).scrollTop()` scrolls to the top of the document all day. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3464890/434340) is a better explanation.

Comment: As @George Ivankin said - this will not working in Chrome. This worked for me: $('html body').scrollTop(0);

Comment: @d2burke `scrollTop()` is a getter and `scrollTop(value)` is a setter. `scrollTop()` without arguments does not change the scroll position.

Comment: This answer is marked as the right answer but considering the confusion it creates with this false statement, "Both scroll to the top of the object", should it not be edited? As  a few have noted here, scrollTop() with no argument is a getter.

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop(0)` is the best solution worked on my tests.

Comment: What's the JavaScript way? (not JQuery)

Comment: @M98 window.scrollTo(x,y)

Answer (score 39):

First, you need to understand the difference between `window` and `document`. The `window` object is a top level client side object. There is nothing above the `window` object. JavaScript is an object orientated language. You start with an object and apply methods to its properties or the properties of its object groups. For example, the `document` object is an object of the `window` object. To change the `document`'s background color, you'd set the `document`'s `bgcolor` property.

```
window.document.bgcolor = "red"
```

To answer your question, There is no difference in the end result between `window` and `document` `scrollTop`. Both will give the same output.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/7VRvj/6/

In general use `document` mainly to register events and use `window` to do things like `scroll`, `scrollTop`, and `resize`.

Comment: No difference in the end result. Both will give the same output.

Comment: Apprently not, some browsers do not support window scroll as the window object may not be the object that is overflowing.

Comment: What browser do not support window, be specific. Here's an example  http://jsfiddle.net/7VRvj/4/. Check it in all browsers and let me know which browser it's not working on.

Answer (score 4):

Cross browser way of doing this is

```
var top = ($(window).scrollTop() || $("body").scrollTop());
```

Comment: Note: `$("body").scrollTop()` always return 0 in Google Chrome.

Comment: `$("body").scrollTop()` is deprecated, [does not work on Chrome or FF anymore](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766938). It will return 0

Answer (score 0):

I've just had some of the similar problems with `scrollTop` described here.

In the end I got around this on **Firefox** and **IE** by using the selector `$('*').scrollTop(0);`

Not perfect if you have elements you don't want to effect but it gets around the Document, Body, HTML and Window disparity. If it helps...

Comment: You should never use * this way (in fact, avoid * altogether). Instead of targeting one element, you're affecting the entire DOM. Huge performance hit. Selectors should be as precise as possible.

Comment: I personally have always used `$("html,body").scrollTop(val)` -- never had any issues