# jQuery $(window).scroll and Internet Explorer (8-9)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scroll

http://jsfiddle.net/CbL7W/ example of scroll event behavior.

I have this script that is working correctly in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
var stickyNavigationOffsetTop = $('.top-nav').offset().top;
var stickyNavigation = function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > stickyNavigationOffsetTop) {
        $('.top-nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'opacity': .8 });
    } else {
        $('.top-nav').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'opacity': 1 });
    }
};
stickyNavigation();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    stickyNavigation();
});
```

But there is a little problem with Internet Explorer:
On the same page I have that script I have a link with a script that hides a div, when this happens sometimes the page completely scrolls back to the top of the page, but IE is not firing `$(window).scroll` when that happens.

Screenshot of the issue when page goes back to top.

Chrome (OK):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WJx7.jpg

IE (Wrong):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXbKk.jpg

Comment: I don't think any scrolling should occur when the page gets shorter. You could try changing scrolltop before you remove the div.

Comment: But why are Chrome and Firefox firing the scroll event? The thing with that div is that is a collapsable section, whe are not actually removing but hiding it.

Comment: In my case (OP's could be different) Chrome and Firefox fire the scroll event because hiding the div causes the scroll bar to be removed from the window. This means that the scroll position has changed back to 0 by default, which I'd say constitutes a scroll event.

Comment: Exactly! but IE guys just need to be different :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue, and as much as I dislike it, my work-around is to trigger the window.scroll event when I show/hide the div. $(window).trigger('scroll');

Comment: It kinda work hehe... mixed with jquery delay as seen on http://blog.project-sierra.de/archives/1559 it's a good workaround. IE is still a little buggy with this solution so our final call was to remove this sticky navigation feature. Thanks anyway for the solution!

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for my issue with IE not firing the scrolling event when a href would pop the page to the top, even though it works fine in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371139/window-scrolltop-vs-document-scrolltop)

I think changing

```
$(window).scrollTop() to 
$(document).scrollTop()
```

may resolve the IE issue.

Comment: Well sorry about that, do you have a dev page where this can be accessed?