# scrollTop not working on chrome and safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on http://www.modsagency.com/home this page and trying animate logo size with scroll down. my jquery code is

```
jQuery('#scrlBdy').scroll(function(e) {
    var y = jQuery("#scrlBdy").scrollTop();
    var x = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    console.log(y);
    console.log(x);
}
```

it working on firefox well but on chrome and safari it return always 0 scrolltop. you can check on chrome console panel.
I need it fix shortly for my client, please anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$(window).scrollTop()`? It is known to be the most cross-browser compatible way of fetching scroll positions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371139/window-scrolltop-vs-document-scrolltop

Comment: yes I tried but not working yet :(

Comment: @Terry Looks like OP wants to peek a scroll position of a particular element (unless `#scrlBdy` is `document.body`).

Comment: you are right Teemu, but I declare body id is #scrlBdy

Comment: Then Terry's suggestion should work.

Comment: does #scrlBdy actually exist on the page? Can you see it in the Elements pane in the dev tools?

Comment: @Teemu I have changed the $(document) to $(window) but still not working.

Comment: @alexnewmann Yes #scrlBdy is exist on html dom. you can check

Comment: Looks like it is all the overflow:auto lines in the code.

Comment: @epascarello yes I find one answer from a forum and try it to put css html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}   but still not work.... any better suggestion?

Comment: Try removing the overflow-x, overflow-y and overflow css rules for body and html. When I disable them in chrome jQuery('#scrlBdy').scrollTop() works fine.