# Simple scroll javascript - Can I add a class to multiple other classes cleanly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just wondering if there is a way to condense this script? My JS is pretty rough, but it seems like I should be able to just insert an or operator to add the class of shrink to any class that passes, I can't seem to get the syntax correct though. It just seems like a lot of redundancy.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.nav a').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('.nav a').removeClass('shrink');
  }
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.navbar-brand').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

Or is there a way to add a class to all children of a given element?

Answer (score 7):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('nav, nav a, .navbar-brand').toggleClass('shrink', $(this).scrollTop() > 50);
});
```

Using the [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to target all matching elements, and [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to toggle the class based on the second argument, being the "state".
`this` references the `window` inside the event handler, and `$(window).scrollTop()` [should be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371139/window-scrolltop-vs-document-scrolltop) as `$(document).scrollTop()` 99.99% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
       $('nav, .nav a, .navbar-brand').addClass('shrink');
    } 
  else {
       $('nav, .nav a, .navbar-brand').removeClass('shrink');
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('nav, .nav a, .navbar-brand').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
        $('nav, .nav a, .navbar-brand').removeClass('shrink');
    }
});
```

Have a look at:
https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/