# Firefox jQuery/JavaScript scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am trying to get my page to scroll to the top. It works in Chrome but not Firefox.  I have read threads on here and tried them, but none have worked. These are the ones I have tried.

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
jQuery(window).scrollTop();
jQuery(window).scrollTo();
jQuery(window).scrollTo(0,0);
```

Comment: I'm going to assume that by "Mozilla" you mean Firefox, edit back if not. Mozilla is the organization that makes the browser, not the browser's name.

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: It isn't being called, just running it in script tags at the bottom of the page, idea being when all html and other javascript code runs then it will last and move the page to the top (its loading at the bottom currently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll top should be triggered on the document element

```
$(document).scrollTop(0);
```

You may also use the [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) if you wanna to add an slow effect

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
```

Comment: See this topic for more informations [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371139/window-scrolltop-vs-document-scrolltop)

Comment: Still the same switching to document... works in Chrome but not in Firefox.