# Fix Nav Bar after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to fix a nav bar after a x point on scroll, but it's not working, can anyone help me? (i'm new, so take it easy)

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (event) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 550 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 550) {      
      $('.nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
  else {
      $('.nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you are scrolling the body element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 550) {
        $('.nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    } else {
        $('.nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should probably explain your answer.

Comment: Here is full answer why use (window) > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371139/window-scrolltop-vs-document-scrolltop

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you are comfortable/with jQuery, you could try something like this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 550) {
        $('.nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    } else {
        $('.nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as the best solution if this worked for you.