# JQuery .scroll - How do I retrieve the distance scrolled down OR up the page?

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-position

I have a Position Fixed Nav at the top of my webpage. The Nav also has a drop down menu which slides down and stays down until it is clicked again.

What I am trying to achieve is, if the sub menu is open, and the user decides to scroll down the page a bit, the sub menu will automatically close.

What I currently have is:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {

$(".subMenu").slideUp(300);

 });
```

But this method is far to sensitive and closes the drop down with the slightest scroll.

Ideally I could have the menu slide back up AFTER I scroll UP or DOWN 300px, so that there is some sort of "buffer" room.

Comment: you could check the absolute scroll position, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464876/javascript-get-window-x-y-position-for-scroll

Answer (score 7):

You can use jquery's `$(window).scrollTop()` to determinate current position. I created a [simple example](http://plnkr.co/edit/zkhusXn6wrp83nQDppN6?p=preview) to demonstrate it.

```
var lastFixPos = 0;
var threshold = 200;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var diff = Math.abs($(window).scrollTop() - lastFixPos);
  if(diff > threshold){
    alert('Do something');
    lastFixPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  }
});
```

You can change the `threshold` to increase/decrease sensitivity before take an action.

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery, you can achieve the same thing like this:

```
var winPos = {
    y: 0,
    yDiff: 0,
    moveY: function(diff) {
      this.yDiff = -(this.y - diff);
      this.y = diff;
    }
};

window.onscroll(function(){
    var threshold = 10;
    winPos.moveY(window.scrollTop);
    // Check against position
    if (winPos.y > threshold) {
        // Do something
    }
    // Check against difference
    if (winPos.yDiff > threshold) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```