# Change margin-top with PURE Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll, margin

I wanted to change margin-top of a div which has `margin-top:80px;` by default. When people scroll the page down it should change its `margin-top:40px` . This has to be done in JS. I searched on web about this and all i could get is a tutorial on JQuery. Could any one help me with pure JS. I dont want JQuery or any other framework as it loads all code for this simple one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: So how about telling us... what have you tried?

Comment: Post a piece of code for us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get window X/Y position for scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464876/javascript-get-window-x-y-position-for-scroll).

Comment: Great question, upvoted, maybe you should accept an answer that is highly-esteemed by the community.

Answer (score 14):

```js
document.getElementById('YouDiv').style.marginTop='40px';
```

```css
#YouDiv {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>This is other Div</div>
<div id="YouDiv">This is YouDiv</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
window.onscroll = function() { document.getElementById('id').style.margin = '40px 0 0 0' }
```