# (doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0) return 'Window' object

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I just want to get the scrollTop of document and use the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464876/javascript-get-window-x-y-position-for-scroll). But what I get is a 'Window' object. I have tested with IE 10, Chrome and Firefox.
Here is my code:

```
    var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
    var left = (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0);
    var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);

    scroll = {
        top: (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0),
        left: (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0)
    };


    console.log(scroll.top); // return 0
    console.log(top); // return object 'Window'
```

I think it's a simple question but I can't figure out why it will return an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `top` is in the window scope. I can reference it with `window.top` or `window.left`. The problem with `window.top` is already defined. [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.top) refers to the top most window in the hierarchy. The browser is not letting you set that variable.

You would need to define it as a different variable or make change the scope so it does not conflict with the global [window] namespace.

Comment: +1 Nice thinking, I thought it was a scope issue. It makes sense that `window.top` is not writeable, so if all that code is in the global scope that would cause it as well (and is a more accurate answer based on the OP's code).

Comment: Yes, just like you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your `console.log` is not within an inner scope of your `var top` declaration.

When you reference `top` you would not be referring to the variable you declared, but instead to `window.top`:

```
console.log(top); // global variable `window.top`: window object

;(function(){
  var top = 0;

  console.log(top); // local variable `top`: 0

})();

console.log(top); // global variable `window.top`: window object
```