# How to Add Smooth Scrolling Back To Top Button using react js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have implemented this using jquery but want to create a component in react to do the same

```
<script>            
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = 220;
    var duration = 500;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            jQuery('.move-top').fadeIn(duration);
        } else {
            jQuery('.move-top').fadeOut(duration);
        }
    });

    jQuery('.move-top').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
        return false;
    })
});
</script>
```

In my page footer

```
<a href="#" class="move-top">↑</a>
```

Comment: If this is for your own personal learning of react, then this is a good small piece of code to learn. But if this is supposed to be used for an actual product, Why bring in react to do something this simple?

Comment: It is for learning only.I wanted do it in react way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, we need to track the page as it's scrolled in the state of the component.  This tracking should only be happening while the component is mounted.  This can be done like so:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return { scrollTop: 0 };
},
componentWillMount: function() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},
handleScroll: function() {
   this.setState({scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop()});
},
```

Note: this is still using jQuery to get the current scroll position.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3464876/5111146) for doing this without jQuery.

Then we need to render the component:

```
scrollToTop: function() {
  $(window).animate({scrollTop: 0}, this.props.duration);
},
render: function() {
  if (this.state.scrollTop < this.props.offset) {
    return null;
  }

  return <a href="#" className="move-top" onClick={this.scrollToTop}>↑</a>
}
```

This is still using jQuery to do the actual scrolling.  Have a look a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8917921/5111146) for scrolling without jQuery.

If you want this component to fade in and out, you should wrap it in a `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` and use CSS animations.  This is documented on the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html).

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rw2wrnhr/1/) demo.

Answer (score 9):

If you'd like to avoid jQuery altogether

```
var Example = React.createClass({
    scrollUp: function () {
        var doc = document.documentElement;
        var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);

        if (top > 0) {
            window.scrollTo(0, top - 15)
            setTimeout(this.scrollUp, 10)
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return (<div><h1>Page Header</h1>
            <div ref="container" className="container">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
                    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
                    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
                    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
                    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
                    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
                    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
                    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>

                <a className="move-top" onClick={this.scrollUp}>Up</a>
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do note the browser compatibility of window.scrollTo here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

After searching on google, I reached a jQuery code as your needs in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/9fe77anq/) . Then, I reordered your jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.move-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.move-top').fadeOut();
    }
  });

  $('.move-top').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

.move-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 100px;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Page Header</h1>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <a class="move-top" href="#">↑</a>
</div>
<h3>Page Footer</h3>
```

Comment: I need a simple implementation of this in reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code like this :

```
smoothScroll.scrollTo(ID_OF_DOM_ELEMENT, OPTIONAL_CALLBACK_ON_SCROLL_DONE)
```

Code :

```
var smoothScroll = {

    timer: null,

    stop: function () {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    },

    scrollTo: function (id, callback) {
        var settings = {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: {
                outQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
                    return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;
                }
            }
        };
        var percentage;
        var startTime;
        var node = document.getElementById(id);
        var nodeTop = node.offsetTop;
        var nodeHeight = node.offsetHeight;
        var body = document.body;
        var html = document.documentElement;
        var height = Math.max(
            body.scrollHeight,
            body.offsetHeight,
            html.clientHeight,
            html.scrollHeight,
            html.offsetHeight
        );
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight
        var offset = window.pageYOffset;
        var delta = nodeTop - offset;
        var bottomScrollableY = height - windowHeight;
        var targetY = (bottomScrollableY < delta) ?
            bottomScrollableY - (height - nodeTop - nodeHeight + offset):
            delta;

        startTime = Date.now();
        percentage = 0;

        if (this.timer) {
            clearInterval(this.timer);
        }

        function step () {
            var yScroll;
            var elapsed = Date.now() - startTime;

            if (elapsed > settings.duration) {
                clearTimeout(this.timer);
            }

            percentage = elapsed / settings.duration;

            if (percentage > 1) {
                clearTimeout(this.timer);

                if (callback) {
                    callback();
                }
            } else {
                yScroll = settings.easing.outQuint(0, elapsed, offset, targetY, settings.duration);
                window.scrollTo(0, yScroll);
                this.timer = setTimeout(step, 10);
            }
        }

        this.timer = setTimeout(step, 10);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [`react-scroll`](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll) is worth being mentioned, add this to your component's `click` handler (`onClick={this.handleClick}`)

```
import Scroll from 'react-scroll'

...
Scroll.animateScroll.scrollToTop({options})
...
```

With options being an object specified as per [Props/Options](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll#propsoptions)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend mixing jQuery and React/Angular. It can be done easily using '[react-scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll)' like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { animateScroll as scroll } from 'react-scroll';

class Scrolltotop extends Component {

    ScrollTo() {
        scroll.scrollToTop();
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="move-top-wrap">                 
                <div onClick={this.ScrollTo} class="move-top">↑</div> 
            </div>
        );

    }

}
export default Scrolltotop;
```

You can check out all [basic examples of react-scroll usage here](https://codesandbox.io/s/py5opl2280).

You can now import and use this component anywhere.