# jQuery element not changing on correct function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I want to have a navbar that automatically shows up when you are not on the top of the page, that is working; the thing is when I scroll back to the top nothing changes. Could somebody look at my code and tell me what I need to change or update?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
      $("#topnav").animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 300);
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
      console.log("done");
      $("#topnav").css({
        opacity: 0
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The `console` does give me a return, yet the page does not seem to change..

Comment: @Santi The code posted here is absolutely not an MCVE. There is no markup for it to operate on, and no way for us to actually run the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suppose, I guess I just feel that a flag and the original complaint may have been satisfactory, without the need for a second snarky "PHPBB" comment.

Comment: @Amorandron - see this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3464890/104380

Comment: you should use `css` to do these transitions, and add a class for "on" state, to have the opacity transitioned using `opacity:1; transition:.3s` for example

Comment: Add a CSS transition to #topnav, and instead of using animate(), use another css() to change the opacity to 1. Also fix the sintax on css():
CSS:
    #topnav{ opacity:0; transition: .3s;}
css():
                $("#topnav").css("opacity", "0");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
   $("#topnav").animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
}
```

is queuing a LOT of animations on `#topnav` and so trying to change the element mid animation won't have an effect.

You can set a flag to see ensure the animation is limited to one time. For example:

```
var flag = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
        if(!flag){
            $("#topnav").animate({opacity: 1}, 300, function(){
              flag = false;
            });
              flag = true;
            }
        }
        else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
            console.log("done");
            $("#topnav").css({opacity: 0});
        }
})
```

Comment: Nope, still doesnt work

Comment: is "done" getting logged?

Comment: Yes it is getting logged

Comment: it does not need quotes, that is a wrong answer. I never ever use quotes.

Comment: Should be: $("#topnav").css('opacity','0');

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @vsync Quotes aren't always necessary, but try doing {margin-bottom: -75px} and let me know how that goes ;)

Comment: @Pat - since I am using jQuery since version 1 (for over 10 years) I have the very basic knowledge of how the DOM and jQuery works, and would obviously know to write `marginBottom` since it is illegal to pass keywords with dashes, spaces and such.