# Javascript addEventListener working in Firefox and IE but not Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, addeventlistener

This works in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but does not work in Chrome, I have tested on multiple computers running Chrome.

Is there something I have missed that causes this not to work in Chrome?

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
    var dealBar = function() {
        var scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var sidebarDeals = document.querySelector('#sidebar__deals');
        var sidebarAdverts = document.querySelector('#sidebar__adverts');
        var adBottom = sidebarAdverts.offsetTop + sidebarAdverts.clientHeight;

        if (scroll > adBottom) {
            sidebarDeals.className = "sidebar__deals--fixed";
        } else {
            sidebarDeals.className = "sidebar__deals--relative";
        }       
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        dealBar();
    });
    dealBar();
});
</script>
```

I get no errors in the Console.

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: In Firefox and Internet Explorer it changes the class name when scroll is more than adBottom, in Chrome it does nothing at all.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] demo

Comment: where did you add your code? it's working for me https://jsfiddle.net/ar4rd6jz/

Comment: Just for fun play around with `document.documentElement.scrollTop`, including things like `document.body.scrollTop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't a problem with the event listener.

Changing

```
var scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

to

```
var scroll = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);
```

This done the trick, seems Chrome bases its scroll position off of `<body>` and Firefox bases it off of `<html>`.

Chrome was returning 0 for scroll causing the function not to trigger the class change.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correclty triggered when I remove the first part related to the `DOMContentLoaded` event: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/tucbehh0/1/).

I think your problem lies here, Chrome probably executes your code *after* the DOM is loaded, thus your code is never executed.

Try to remove this part:

```
<script>
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
    var dealBar = function() {
        var scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var sidebarDeals = document.querySelector('#sidebar__deals');
        var sidebarAdverts = document.querySelector('#sidebar__adverts');
        var adBottom = sidebarAdverts.offsetTop + sidebarAdverts.clientHeight;

        if (scroll > adBottom) {
            sidebarDeals.className = "sidebar__deals--fixed";
        } else {
            sidebarDeals.className = "sidebar__deals--relative";
        }       
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        dealBar();
    });
    //dealBar();
//});
</script>
```

Also, regarding the scroll position, you may want to check this post: [JavaScript get window X/Y position for scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464876/javascript-get-window-x-y-position-for-scroll)

Comment: Tried this, but not luck. 

I added consolelog(1) and on scrolling it is logging 1, so must be something else in the rest of the script that Chrome doesn't like.

Comment: I just did console.log(scroll); in the function and in chrome it is returning 0.

var scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop; Is the problem in chrome, is there something there that doesn't work with chrome?

Comment: @ash I think you may find this post useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464876/javascript-get-window-x-y-position-for-scroll