# How to change position of block in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have `div` element on the page:

```
<div #draggable></div>

@ViewChild('draggable') private draggableElement: ElementRef;
```

I listen scroll event and try change position of this block:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event){
    this.draggableElement.nativeElement.clientTop = 200;
  }
```

But it does not work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the element has an absolute position, you can set the `left` and `top` style attributes:

```
this.draggableElement.nativeElement.style.left = "100px";
this.draggableElement.nativeElement.style.top = "200px";
```

An alternative is to move it with a CSS transform:

```
this.draggableElement.nativeElement.style.transform = "translateX(100px)";
this.draggableElement.nativeElement.style.transform = "translateY(200px)";
this.draggableElement.nativeElement.style.transform = "translate(100px, 200px)";
```

Comment: Thank you, how to get coordinates of window from `$event`?

Comment: You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3464876/1009922).

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/442404/1009922) gives various techniques to get the position of an element (if that is what you meant by the "window"). You can also retrieve the current values of the `left` and `top` style attributes of the element.

Comment: And [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8cyr2p) uses `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` to get the scroll position.