# How do I get the value of a vertical scrollbar in a scrollable HTML table using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, scrollbar

I have a table with a vertical scroll bar. When the application goes off to another page and comes back again, I need to return the table to where it was before to save the user having to scroll back to it. In other words, I need to be able to determine how far down the table had been scrolled.

This is the css I use to make the table scrollable:

```
.table-scroll tbody {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 450px;
}

.table-scroll tr {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: inline-table;
}

.table-scroll thead > tr > th {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to get the value of a scroll bar but the x-position of the element or document. Then you need to save the value in either local or session storage depending on what your requirements are.

Comment: And how would I get the x-position?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464876/javascript-get-window-x-y-position-for-scroll

Comment: The table doesn't move and I'm not concerned as to its position. It's the scroll bar I'm interested in but I can see no way to reference it.