# CSS I want a div to be on top of everything

Tags: html, css

How do I make an html div tag to be on top of everything? I tried adding `z-index: 1000`, but it remains the same.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

In order for z-index to work, you'll need to give the element a `position:absolute` or a `position:relative` property. Once you do that, your links will function properly, though you may have to tweak your CSS a bit afterwards.

Comment: I wanted to use a fixed scheme and so I kept the position as fixed but still set the z-index to 1000 and got the desired results, it covered a div lower on the page as I scrolled, can you explain why that happened even though I was using a static position?

Comment: Another thing that can cause element A to appear "below" element B is if element A spills outside its parent P's bounding rectangle (and spills into B's bounding rectangle) and P's style is set to "overflow:hidden".

Answer (score 116):

Yes, in order for the `z-index` to work, you'll need to give the element a `position: absolute` or a `position: relative` property... fine.

##### But... pay attention to parents!

###### The element's z-index may be limited by its parent's z-index value.

You have to go down the nodes of the elements to check if at the level of the common parent the first descendants have a defined z-index.

###### All other descendants can never be in the foreground if at the base there is a lower definite `z-index`.

In this snippet example, `div1-2-1` has a `z-index` of 1000 but is nevertheless under the `div1-1-1` which has a z-index of 3.

This is because div1-1 has a z-index greater than div1-2.

[image]

```css
.div {
  
}

#div1 {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#div1-1 {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 31px;
  background-color: indianred;
}

#div1-1-1 {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

#div1-2 {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 80px;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

#div1-2-1 {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 10px;
  color: red;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.rotate {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="div1">div1</br>z-index: 1
  <div class="div" id="div1-1">div1-1</br>z-index: 2
    <div class="div" id="div1-1-1">div1-1-1</br>z-index: 3</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div" id="div1-2">div1-2</br>z-index: 1</br><span class='rotate blink'><=</span>
    <div class="div" id="div1-2-1"><span class='blink'>z-index: 1000!!</span></br>div1-2-1</br><span class='blink'> because =></br>(same</br>   parent)</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### More simply :

[image]

Comment: In your example the root parent div `div1` has a defined z-index of 1, that would mean all children can only have z-index of 1. But clearly `div1-1` is infront of `div1-2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The parent div had a lower z-index in my case.

Comment: Is there any way around this even if the z-index is set different in the parents? anyway to override this?

Answer (score 50):

For `z-index:1000` to have an effect you need a non-static positioning scheme.

Add `position:relative;` to a rule selecting the element you want to be on top

Answer (score 16):

You need to add `position:relative;` to the menu. Z-index only works when you have a non static positioning scheme.

Answer (score 13):

`z-index` property enables you to take your control at front. the bigger number you set the upper your element you get.

`position` property should be `relative` because position of `html-element` should be position relatively against other controls in all dimensions.

```
element.style {
   position:relative;
   z-index:1000; //change your number as per elements lies on your page.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I gonna assumed you making a popup with code from WW3 school, correct? 
check it css. the .modal one, there're already word `z-index` there. just change from 1 to 100.

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** If there are `z-index` assigned to other elements on the page, then you need to adjust `z-index` value for the dialog element too.

It seems like nesting an element inside a [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement) element puts it on top of everything. It is placed both horizontally and vertically centered to the screen if you use [`showModal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) but you lose the interactivity with other elements in the page.

```js
document.querySelector("dialog").showModal();
```

```html
<dialog>
  <div class="element">I am on top of everything else</div>
</dialog>
<div class="backdrop">Backdrop element</div>
```

If you still want interactivity with the background elements, you can use the [`show()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/show) method. It is placed only horizontally centered to the screen.

```js
document.querySelector("dialog").show();
```

```html
<dialog>
  <div class="element">I am on top of everything else</div>
</dialog>
<div class="backdrop">Backdrop element to check if I am underneath or not.</div>
```