# Make div display on top of everything

Tags: css

I'm using a countdowntimer on my website for shipping.

This my code I added in my header.tpl : http://jsfiddle.net/ALrnK/3/

```
    <div id="leveransinfo">
        <img src="http://mobilprylar.nu/img/frakt.png"/> 
        <img id="posten" src="http://mobilprylar.nu/img/s/17.jpg"/>
         <div id="timeleft"></div></div>
           <div id="levinfo">
           <b>Leveransinformation</b></br>
           </br>
           ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent</br>
           ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent</br>
           </br>
           ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent</br>
          </br>
              </div>
```

I'f you take look att (link was removed due to canceled project) and hover the countdowntimer it extends the header.

I would like the information to show there but on top of everything else. So its displays over the menu and the imageslider.

I tried to use z-index but it does not matter how I do. Is there anything else I should use instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS I want a div to be on top of everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421775/css-i-want-a-div-to-be-on-top-of-everything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the actual styles, here's one possibility - Make sure the element that you are changing the z-index of is either `position: relative;`, absolute, or fixed.

Comment: Thx, I missted the position!