# bootstrap.min.css sets transparency where not wanted

Tags: css

I have a small chatbox at the bottom of my page which seems to be inheriting CSS style from bootstrap.min.css and that chatbox is transparent which is a nuisance because the underlying text on the page shows through and what is worse, is that hyperlinks on the page are over-riding clickable areas in the chatbox for opening, closing and submitting messages.

I have tried adding CSS style to the chatbox for opacity and rgba. Even tried adding a background image but to no effect.

I have since modified the chatbox to display an iFrame from a different site that does not use bootstrap.min.css.

But even the iFrame page is affected by transparency. I can remove the transparency setting in bootstrap.min.css but that will not solve my bigger problem... I am intending to use this chatbox on several sites and may not have control of the site's CSS.

So I need a way to override the parent site's CSS just for the chatbox.

If that is impossible, then I can  weed out the transparency from bootstrap.min.css that is used on my own sites. However I do wonder what is the point of such transparency when it is useless here...

[image: transparency is useless here]

Comment: Please, paste the full code you tried (or make a jsfiddle) because I created a https://jsfiddle.net/3m7s0tj2/ with the page you provided, I included bootstrap and there is no transparency problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a z-index problem which is common when integrating iframes, apply `z-index: 2000;` (or whatever number as long as it comes on top) on your `chatbox` div so your chatbox will still stay upfront.

Comment: I can see that you changed your code, you shouldn't, just change your chatbox div like so `<div class="chatbox chatbox--tray chatbox--empty" style="z-index: 2000">`

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any code, I'm not sure if you've tried this or not, but you can use the `!important` value to override Bootstrap's styles in your custom CSS. For example:
`background-color: white !important`;

Comment: Already tried -    background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245); 
    background: rgba(245, 245, 245); 
    background-image: url('/images/chatbox-bgd.gif'); 
    opacity: 1; 
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;

Comment: Okay, I would recommend that you take a look at this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421775/css-i-want-a-div-to-be-on-top-of-everything
So you might need to wrap a div around all of the elements in the chatbox (besides the root chatbox element) and give it the `position: relative` rule. Try that in addition to a `z-index:100` on that new element.

Comment: Position: relative or absolute moves the chatbox from where it is supposed to be. But the z-index: 1000 solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: No problem! You can also get rid of that horizontal scroll on the page by adding `class="container"` to `body` or `style="overflow-x:hidden;"`

Comment: Thanks but scroll is needed because it shows the last 4 messages which can vary in length. I think the client needs to see at least the last 2 questions with answers. I know I do when I am the client because often I have to copy and paste my previous question because support ignored it.

Comment: However what I do need now to complete this project is a means to keep the chatbox open when the client moves to another page or reloads. So perhaps setting a cookie for open or closed and retrieving it on page load to set the option on the chatbox CSS.