# Contex/popup menu is cut on splitter of golden layout

Tags: javascript, css, golden-layout

I would like to show a context menu for the items in a tree view.
The menu should be shown on top of all other element and it should
also cross the borders of a GoldenLayout (http://golden-layout.com/).
However, the menu is "cut" on the split pane:

[image]

I tried to set an absolute `position` and increase the `z-index`.
That did not help. Maybe the reason is the style `overflow = hidden` for some parent divs?

[image]

**=> If I want to allow my context menu to cross lyout borders, what is the right way/location to modify the GoldenLayout config?**

(I only want the context menu to cross borders, not the other content of the tree view.)

```
var menu = selection.append('div')
           .className('treez-context-menu');
```

---

```
 .treez-context-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none; 
    outline: thin solid lightgrey;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Related:

[CSS I want a div to be on top of everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421775/css-i-want-a-div-to-be-on-top-of-everything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the css position for the menu from absolute to fixed did the trick:

```
.treez-context-menu {
    position: fixed; //changed from absolute to fixed
    z-index: 100;
    display: none; 
    outline: thin solid lightgrey;
    background-color: white;
}
```