# Dialog which allow to click outside

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

I'm looking for a dialog that allows me to click outside of it. There are certainly many examples on the web, but I have no idea what this type of dialogue might be called. For clarity, I am looking for something similar to the dialogue that appears in Google Drive during the uplod file, it allows you to continue working on the dashboard while the file is being transferred and dialog is still open. Maybe in Angular Material dialog allows such settings but I don't know what to set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a component is quite easy to create by yourself. 
Create a component which contains any headers and close buttons. Its important to use ng-content to be able to fill any gui inside the 'outerbox'. Read this: https://medium.com/@joshblf/wtf-is-ng-content-8382b2a664e1.

Add css to the outerbox (ex: @HostBinding('class')) that makes it float in any place you want. ex: [Float a div above page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006134/float-a-div-above-page-content)
Clicking on the close button, or what ever you want closes it by change the class on the outerbox.